# React/Html dragging and dropping items between two lists

Tags: react.js, html5, jsx

I am implementing two lists with draggable items. The items can be re-arranged within each list or can be inserted to another list.

I had some difficulty implementing the drag and drop behavior when one list is empty. I ended up adding an `if(parentNode.nodeName === "DIV"` conditional which I am not particularly proud of. Would appreciate comments or suggestions directly addressing my handleDrop implementation especially when dragging list items to empty list.

General comments/feedback appreciated as well.

```
import React from 'react';
export const App = () => {

  let draggedElem;
  const handleDrop = (e) => {

    let parentElem = e.target.parentNode;
    parentElem.insertBefore(draggedElem, e.target)
    if(parentElem.nodeName === "DIV"){
      e.target.insertBefore(draggedElem, null)
    }

  }

  const handleDragStart = (e) => {
    draggedElem = e.target;
  }

  const handleDrag = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
  
  return (
    <div id="container" style={{margin: "10px"}}>
      <h2>List One </h2>

      <div>
        <ul id="list1"  style={{minWidth:'50px', minHeight:"50px"}}>
          <li onDragOver={handleDrag} onDrop={handleDrop} onDragStart={handleDragStart} draggable>One</li>
          <li onDragOver={handleDrag} onDrop={handleDrop} onDragStart={handleDragStart}  draggable>Two</li>
          <li onDragOver={handleDrag} onDrop={handleDrop} onDragStart={handleDragStart}  draggable>Three</li>
        </ul>

      </div>

      <h2> List Two</h2>
      <div>

        <ul id="list2" onDragOver={handleDrag} onDrop={handleDrop} style={{minWidth:'50px', minHeight:"50px"}}>
          <li draggable onDragOver={handleDrag} onDrop={handleDrop} onDragStart={handleDragStart}>Hello World</li>
        </ul>

      </div>


    </div>
  )


}
```

Comment: You mentioned that empty-list is a corner case. Consider designing that out of the problem space. You might turn empty lists into a list with a single "visibility: hidden;" element. Or you might consider ensuring that the last element of a list shall _always_ be such a hidden element, if that's simpler to implement.